# How to get 5.1 sound working on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have my digital wire hooked to my 5.1 Logitech Z680 speakers. They are old, but good. I just re-installed Windows 7 after some issues, and now I can't get surround sound to work. If I test sound on "Digital Output" it is always silent, vs SPDIF which I've read is always stereo (but works). My motherboard is an Asus P5Q-E, with latest drivers as far as I can tell, with SoundMax installed. Totally clueless how I had gotten 5.1 working previously.

[image: Sound]

Comment: First thing to do is to ensure your testing application is set to send 5.1 sound and the file you are testing against supports it. VLC is pretty easy to configure since you don't need external filters like AC3/DTS. Then set your speakers as the default output device, instead of the SPDIF port. Confirm that your sound card output jacks are correctly identified in the speakers object, and that its using the SoundMax HD audio controller.

Comment: Check the Control Panel.  Is there a SoundMax audio manager?

Comment: SoundMax is a prettier interface than the regular sound controller. I tried playing with both. I also tried using speakers as default and could not get 5.1. Just upgraded to Windows 10 to get new drivers and see if that helps. I finally have time to play around again - the old drivers don't work at all so I'm soundless for the time being.

Comment: I unfortunately didn't realize my motherboard doesn't have drivers for Windows 10.... so now I'm completely soundless. Think I should delete this question eh?